# How to read route53 record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

When I see route 53 records. like following data existed. But I couldn't understand how to read them.
I understand `A` records represents domainname's IPv4 address. but `123xyz.cloudfront.net.`was represented in this record.
What is this?

```
Record name　　　　　　　　　　　　Type　　　Routing policy　Differentiator　Value/Route traffic to
beta.test.example.com   A   　　　Simple   　　　　　　- 　　　　　　　　　　　　　123xyz.cloudfront.net.
beta.test.example.com   AAAA　　　Simple   　　　　　　- 　　　　　　　　　　　　　123xyz.cloudfront.net.
beta.test.example.com   NS  　　　Simple   　　　　　　- 　　　　　　　　　　　　　ns-1037.awsdns-01.org.
                                                            　　ns-891.awsdns-47.net.
                                                            　　ns-1996.awsdns-57.co.uk.
                                                            　　ns-113.awsdns-14.com.
```

I still haven't understood how to read them. if someone has experienced same issue, will you please let me know. thanks

Comment: Note that this is not really specific to route53 but a general question on how DNS and its records work.

Comment: @luk2302 Only in part. DNS and `A` records type have no concept of "Type simple", "Routing policy" or "Differentiatior".  Those are all specifics to this DNS provider.

Answer (score 2):

The two most popular types of DNS entries are:

- `A-Record`, which resolves the domain name into an IP address
- `CNAME`, which tells DNS start start the domain name resolution again with a different DNS Name (eg point `www.example.com` to `example.com`

However, a **domain apex** (when it does not have a subdomain at the front) cannot have a `CNAME` record -- this means it is not possible to point `example.com` to `www.example.com`. Amazon Route 53 overcomes this with the concept of an **Alias**, which allows a domain apex to point to Amazon S3, Amazon CloudFront and a few other services:

[image: Route 53 Alias]

Your DNS entries are saying:

- The `A` record resolves `beta.test.example.com` to `123xyz.cloudfront.net` (using an Alias)
- The `AAAA` record does the same, but for IPv6
- The `NS` record points to the Name Servers for the Domain Name

Comment: "when it does not have a subdomain at the front" - the first bit isn't usually a subdomain, it's simply an A record / CNAME / etc.